# how to make progress with php in cmd like composer/curl/wget did

Tags: php, cmd, command-line-interface

i have php script like this:

```
echo 'Loading...'.PHP_EOL;
if($download_size > 0)
        {
            echo round($downloaded / $download_size  * 100, 2) .'%'. PHP_EOL;
        }
```

this return

```
Loading ...
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
0%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
0.01%
--snippet--
```

when we use compoeser, the download progress will be like this

`githubUser/githubChannel 75%`

wget/curl/apt-get will be like this

`file.ext [=======>         ] 40%`

how to do this with php run in cli mode?

i try add `system('cls');` after echo but not work

what i want is like this

`progress: 0%`

after few second

`progress: 2%`

after few second

`progress: 6%`

after few second

`progress: 9%`

thanks .

Comment: Not use a newline but a carriage return : `echo round($downloaded / $download_size  * 100, 2) . "%\r";`

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Or where are you stuck at present?

Comment: @gaganshera just dont know what to do. but i have correct answer below. thanks for ur attention. my pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `\r` character (*carriage return*). When "written" to your terminal, the cursor pointing to the column of the next character to be written will be moved to the first column of the actual line.

A complete working example would look like the following snippet:

```
<?php

$download_size = 100;
$downloaded = 0;

echo 'Loading...'.PHP_EOL;
while ($downloaded < $download_size) {
    if($download_size > 0) {
        echo round(($downloaded / $download_size) * 100, 2) . "%\r";
        sleep(1);
        $downloaded += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow `\r` . never know this char. before. thanks bro, you save my day